# Aligning Paragraph Text from Columns

Tags: html, css, padding

So I tried using this came up on a project I was working on and tried to recreate it in an isolated project to see if I could eliminate factors that I wasn't seeing.  Here's some screengrabs but I wanted to use the "Padding-top" css to align the column text.  For some reason it won't work.  Any help would be great.  Thanks All.

[HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrzJY.png)

[CSS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSNCc.png)

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting that space at the top of your first column is because of the empty `h1` element, as well as the margin on your `<p>` element. Move your `h1` outside of `.level` and remove any margin from your `<p>` element, and your two columns will be aligned.

EDIT: I'm guessing you meant for "Something of a Mystery" to be the contents of your `h1`, not the class name...?

```css
.level{columns:2;}
.level p{margin:0;}
```

```html
<h1 class="Something of a Mystery"></h1>
    <div class="level">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus venenatis tempus molestie. Etiam dictum risus quis nibh ullamcorper, quis pulvinar tellus vulputate. Fusce consectetur et dui sed lobortis. Suspendisse luctus risus a nibh lacinia, vel ultricies mi faucibus. In interdum, odio ac faucibus tempor, elit velit fringilla turpis, eget posuere tortor sapien vel lorem.m</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hey Ryan, I'll give this a try.  Thanks so much for your input.  I'm a noob, so these basic questions/answers do help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Column's property (shorthand property that sets both the column-width and column-count properties in a single property). column-count is number of columns into which the element's content should be flowed .

```
/* Column count */
columns: auto;
columns: 2;
```

You just need to set column property(only column-count here) on paragraph element instead of div with class level as you need to split only paragraph element. Now you can set padding top of this paragraph element

```
.level p {
    columns :2;
 }
```

For more information on column property : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns